# Web Services Build Error in Monotouch

Tags: iphone, web-services, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

My project and web services work fine in the simulator but crash when uploading to an iPhone.  It had been working fine before I updated Monotouch from 1.1.  Can I revert back to earlier versions of Monotouch?  Here is the problem:

I have a monotouch app using web services.  When I export the project to Xcode, I get a build error stating:
         System.Web.Services.dll.mdb: No such file or directory

In the folder explorer that file is highlighted in red because there is nothing there.

Does anyone have a working System.Web.Services.dll for the latest version of monodevelop and monotouch?

Here is the stack trace on exit error in xCode:

`Wed Nov 18 10:31:37 unknown SpringBoard[24] : MultitouchHID(208ad0) uilock state: 1 -> 0
Wed Nov 18 10:31:37 unknown SpringBoard[24] : MultitouchHID(2944f0) device bootloaded
Wed Nov 18 10:31:47 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[85] Builtin profile: container (seatbelt)
Wed Nov 18 10:31:47 unknown kernel[0] : launchd[85] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/49398D0F-C9F2-456A-BB84-BA1F91C78243 (seatbelt)
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] : Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute.AddKeyHash (System.Text.StringBuilder sb) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapTypeStubInfo..ctor (System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo logicalTypeInfo) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo.CreateTypeStubInfo (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalTypeInfo.GetTypeStub (System.String protocolName) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.TypeStubManager.GetTypeStub (System.Type t, System.String protocolName) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at GeoQuiz2.GeoQuizRef.TGeoTeachers..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at GeoQuiz2.QuizPicker.ViewDidLoad () [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at GeoQuiz2.AppDelegate.m__0 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] :   at GeoQuiz2.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff][85] : Error connecting stdout and stderr (192.168.1.19:10001)
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] : (UIKitApplication:GeoQuiz2[0x46ff]) Exited with exit code: 1
Wed Nov 18 10:32:04 unknown SpringBoard[24] : Application 'GeoQuiz' exited abnormally with exit status 1`

Using your Web.Services.dll I think I got a shorter stack trace on error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*System.Web.Services.dll.mdb* should be installed. Have you tried reinstalling monotouch?

I've uploaded *System.Web.Services.dll* and *System.Web.Services.dll.mdb* for you to try: [here](http://gonzalo.name/tmp/monotouch-sys-web.zip). Use at your own risk! And you should report the problem and provide any relevant info so that this problem can be fixed for real.

Comment: I don't want to reinstall monotouch because I already paid for the license on this install.  I have System.Web.Services.dll installed as it works great in the simulator.

Comment: Reinstalling won't make your license disappear and if it does, you can reactivate without problems.

Comment: Thanks. Updated question with the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you.  DOes System.Web.Services.dll.mdb go in the Monotouch project or just Xcode?

Comment: It should go wherever System.Web.Services.dll is. Also if the project is missing the file, copy it to where the project expects the file to be.

Comment: The new dll generates the Xcode project correctly including the dll.mdb.   However the project still crashes when uploading to the device.

Comment: Somehow it seems to be working now.  Sometimes after a restart, reopen, full clean, or whatever... stuff starts working again : )